# Failed to AppendChild -- trying to make one method append another in a different class

Tags: javascript, jquery

The code below gives me the following message in the console:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': The new child element contains the parent
```

The render method of the first class is supposed to create an unordered list for which there is a child ordered list (in the Counter.render method), which has direct children.

```
    class CounterList {
  constructor(){
   this.counters = [];
  }
  addNewCounter(counter) {
    this.counters.push(this.Counter);
  }
  render() {
    var $ul = $('body').append("<ul></ul>");
    $ul.append(Counter.render);
    return $ul;

  }
}

class Counter {
  constructor() {
    this.name = $("#new-counter-name").val();
    var count = 0;
  }
  decrement() {
    this.count--;
    renderPage();
  }
  increment() {
    this.count++;
    renderPage();
  }
  render() {
    var li = '<li><span>'+this.name+'</span><button>'+this.decrement+'</button><span>'+this.count+'</span><button>'+this.increment+'</button></li>';
    return li;

  }
}
```

EDIT: I realized I only get this error with the return $ul. Otherwise, no errors, but nothing happens.

Comment: In the `$ul.append` and the `counters.push` function call you also need to reference the counters in `this.counters` and `counter`, rather than the `Counter` object itself.

Answer (score 1):

When you do 
`var $ul = $('body').append("<ul></ul>");`

Your `$ul` is `body`.

You have to do:

`var $ul = $('<ul/>').appendTo('body');`